# Polar to Cartesian image conversion in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, polar-coordinates

I am having problems converting an image in [R,theta] format to [x,y]

I am trying to use interp2.

```
[nZ,nX] = size(im);
theta = ((0:(nX-1)))*0.0071; %0.0071 is known angular separation of columns
rr = (0:(nZ-1))*0.0039; %0.0039 is resolution of rows
```

I then do:

```
%% Create grids and convert polar coordinates to rectangular
[THETA,RR] = meshgrid(theta,rr);
[XX,YY] = pol2cart(THETA,RR);
```

and finally:

```
im_out=interp2(theta,rr,im,XX,YY,'linear');
im_out(isnan(im_out)) = 0;
```

but the image is incorrect!

Here is the input image (figure 1) (with R,theta geometry):

[image]

I want to reconstruct that on a Cartesian grid (using interp2) so it looks like this (figure 2):

[image]

All the data in the Polar image (figure 1) should be mapped into the red sector of the Cartesian image (figure 2).

Comment: Can you show the desired image and the one you get?

Comment: Here is the input image (with R,theta geometry):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5vllc0puftqm9k/input.png?dl=0

I want to reconstruct that on a Cartesian grid (using interp2) so it looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvmprufb5zc3e1a/required_output.png?dl=0

Comment: Do you know where the center of the polar sampling is on the Cartesian one? It's evidently not the upper left corner.

Comment: All the data in the Polar image (figure 1) should be mapped into the red sector of the Cartesian image (figure 2). After using interp2, NAN should be set to 0 (i.e. the blue area of the Cartesian image (ignore the noise in the red area)). (0,0) in the Polar image should map to the top left corner of the red sector in the Cartesian image. Thanks for you help!

Comment: (0,0) in the polar image maps to (274,50) in the Cartesian image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to do this as follows:

I added zeros to top of im matrix to define the radius of curvature (in my case 1018 pixels i.e ROC) and polar origin correctly:

```
im = IML';   % scan_lines (rotated for now)
sector=75;   % [degrees]
im_depth=16; % [cm] (depth + ROC)

ROC=3.98;
im_depth=16+ROC;

col_size=size(im,2);
zeros_row = zeros(1018, col_size);
im=[zeros_row; im];
scan_lines = im;

[nY, nX] = size(im);

min_ang=(sector/nX)*pi/180;% [rad.]
theta = -nX/2*min_ang:min_ang:nX/2*min_ang; % total angle/num. lines [radians]
theta = theta(2:end);

steering_angles=theta; % angles [radians]

num_samples=im_depth/nY;
rr = (0:(nY-1))*num_samples; % im. depth/num. samples
r = rr; 

image_size = [26.15,16+ROC]; % [cm]

x_resolution = 480; % image resolution [pix]
y_resolution = 640;

% assign the inputs
x = image_size(2);
y = image_size(1);

disp_rr=max(rr)/(im_depth-ROC);

%plot input image
%subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(theta*(180/pi), rr/disp_rr, fliplr(IML')); title('polar geometry'); colormap(gray)
%xlabel('theta [deg]')
%ylabel('r [cm]'); hold on;

% number of scan lines
Nt = length(scan_lines(1, :));

% create regular Cartesian grid to remap to
pos_vec_y_new = (0:1/(y_resolution-1):1).*y - y/2;
pos_vec_y_new = pos_vec_y_new';
pos_vec_x_new = (0:1/(x_resolution-1):1).*x;
[pos_mat_x_new, pos_mat_y_new] = ndgrid(pos_vec_x_new, pos_vec_y_new);

% convert new points to polar coordinates
[th_cart, r_cart] = cart2pol(pos_mat_x_new, pos_mat_y_new);

% interpolate using linear interpolation
op = interp2(steering_angles,r, scan_lines, th_cart, r_cart, 'linear').';

% set any values outside of the interpolation range to be 0
% op(isnan(op)) = max(b_mode(:));
op(isnan(op)) = 0;

%plot output image
subplot(2,2,4); 
imagesc(pos_vec_y_new, pos_vec_x_new-ROC, op'); title('Cartesian geometry'); colormap(gray); 
xlabel('lat [cm]')
ylabel('ax [cm]');
caxis([7.2,max(max(op))])
```

Comment: Good job. I started playing around with your image and then had to give up to do actual work.